# Error running Expo app on iOS Simulator

Tags: react-native, expo

When attempting to launch an Expo project from the XDE, I am presented with the following issue where the Expo simulator app will not install:

> Error running `xcrun simctl install booted
>   /Users/username/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-X.Y.Z.app`: An
>   error was encountered processing the command
>   (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22): Failed to install the requested
>   application The bundle identifier of the application could not be
>   determined.
>
> Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value
>   for CFBundleIdentifier.
>
> Error installing or running app. Error: Process exited with non-zero
>   code: 22

Which will display like the following image in the XDE:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a corrupted or incompatible version of the simulator app that is stored on your computer. The Expo Development Environment (XDE) does not resolve this issue automatically.

As mentioned on the Expo and XDE forums, the way to resolve this issue is to navigate to:

> ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/

In the Finder, and delete the file `Exponent-X.Y.Z` where X, Y, and Z represent the version of the app.

Source: https://forums.expo.io/t/error-installing-expo-on-ios-simulator/741